# Proper use of Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE

Tags: android, activeandroid

If I have a relation like this, and what I want is that whenever I call `delete()` on an `User`, the `vehicle` field is also deleted.

```
@Table (name = "Users")
public class User extends Model {
    @Column(name = "Name", unique = true, onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE) name;
    @Column(name = "Vehicle") Vehicle vehicle;
}

@Table (name = "Vehicles")
public class Vehicle extends Model {
    @Column(name = "Name", unique = true, onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE) name;
}
```

I think this can be accomplished by using `onDelete = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE` on `Vehicle.name` but I'm not so sure so I'll just go ahead and ask.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Best check the issues section of ActiveAndroid on GitHub.